# What is meant by "swallowing of a stereotype"?

Tags: gestalt-psychology

In Gestalt Therapy, when describing an adjustment in the field of psychotherpay, the authors write,

> Unfortunately, the “adjustment” of much
> psychotherapy, the “conforming to the reality-principle,” is the swallowing of a
> stereotype.
>
> — Hefferline et al. (1951)

What does this mean?

### References

Hefferline, R. F., Goodman, P., & Perls, F. S. (1951). *Gestalt therapy: excitement and growth in the human personality*. Gouldsboro, ME: The Gestalt Journal Press, Inc.